# Is there a native function in Turtle that resizes an image to fit the window?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is there a function native to the Turtle library that would automatically resize the lines/shapes drawn so they all appear within the window (ie. so lo lines are drawn outside the window)? To clarify, I'm not asking about a way to make the window larger, rather, a function that reduces the size of the things the turtle has drawn.

Searching through the Turtle documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle) there appears to be a function called setworldcoordinates(). It looks like it translates the objects already on the screen to a new coordinate system, which I think could be used to shrink things. If this is correct, is this the simplest method?

Comment: did you try it ? Create code to try it and if you get error then come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example uses `setworldcoordinates` to slowly change size.

```
from turtle import *
import time

screen = getscreen()
screen.setworldcoordinates(-50,-20, 50, 20)

for _ in range(8):
    left(45)
    fd(4)

x = 2.5 # 50/20
y = 1
for i in range(20):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    screen.setworldcoordinates(-50 - x*i, -20 - y*i, 50 + x*i, 20 + y*i)

exitonclick()
```

It seems the simples method to resize all objects but I never used it so I'm wondering if it is really useful.

Comment: I believe this to be the simplest solution but: if you don't consider the physical size of your window, you can screw up your aspect ratio, if that's important to you; because it does a `reset()`, it undoes some screen properties so I tend to use it early in my programs before setting other screen properties.  I can't recall what it does about images.

Comment: @cdlane this confirms my fears that sometimes it may not be so useful.